# Disable WCF binding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

My application runs a WCF service host with 2 different binding (each with different interfaces). Under certain circumstances, I'd like to disable 1 binding so clients that try to connect to this interface/port/binding-name (whatever) don't find anything there.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Almost sounds like security through obscurity. Can't you just reject clients of a particular type if they try to access a service that you don't want them to (i.e. they don't have authorization for)?

Comment: @Yuck My point is not security here. The current project contains a licensing server where applications could license themselves over WCF, but only if the licensing server itself is.. licensed. Because it's a Windows Service I still need a running WCF service host on it for the configuration application. I could run 2 WCF service hosts, but that's just stupid.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple WCF service hosts within the same Windows Service. Having an "always available" WCF service and an "only available when licensed" WCF service is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Going on what [Dhawalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1949572/dhawalk) said, you could abstract out your business layer, and using dependency injection, injecting service handlers with implementations for "not available" and "functional".  The not available implementations could just throw an exception or always return an error.

Answer (score 0):

If both service contracts are on the same service class, I don't see how you would easily disable it beyond adding a check for 'If I am enabled...' at the start of each method.

Maybe you could programattically look at the Operation Contracts of your service host, it may be possible to remove them one at a time. The service host may have to be turned off temporarily to make that change though. I've added methods to a service contract in this way that never existed on the same class/interface as the real service class, and weren't even in the same assembly, but I can't remember if the servicehost had already been started at that time.

You'll need to look at the Endpoints in:
`ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints`
and choose the one you need to edit, then look at
`Endpoint.Contract.Operations`
to determine which methods you want to add/remove. They will disappear from the WSDL.

**EDIT** Just tried this, it seems to work at run time but I can imagine it would be harder to add OperationContracts  back in (unnless you saved them before you removed them... let me know how you get on, it sounds interesting!)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to device your BL, and use WCF inspectors to bounceoff unlicensesd calls. please refer to the following link for inspectors

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx